# How to hide mysql errors in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I use error_reporting(0) code for hiding PHP errors,which always works ,but there are some errors from mysql which are useless, is there any code for mysql to hide the mysql errors like invalid sql ,1064 errors

Comment: You're not concerned that you're generating invalid SQL!?

Comment: it doesn't show errors by default.. you're probably printing them manually.

Comment: Use die(); so you will not see anything. I dont think invalid sql is useless.

Comment: i had album.php in my webiste , in that page i am getting an invalid sql error but ,album.php?cat=2&gall=140&album=96  url has no errors.It shows the relevant data.. If any one open the album.php page it shows an invalid sql . If they go through cat id it shows the related data .

Comment: you forgot to validate the input.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea: Don't.

Turn PHP error reporting back on right now, and FIX those errors instead of sweeping them under the rug.

Personally, I like to use `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)`. While it's not perfect, I ignore notices because the default behaviour is what I want to happen anyway.

Ignoring MySQL errors is a GREAT BIG ***HELL*** NO! ... Well, unless you want a dead server and a million customers pissed at you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = @mysql_operation();
$errno = mysql_errno();
if ($errno > 0)
{
    handle_error();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@` in front of the function calls should suppress any errors generated.

It is [the error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).  I would use this very lightly and try to fix your code that is producing the errors/warning first.

The only time I would use the `@` is when I use third party libraries that have deprecated code.  Using it too much will mask any real issues (like the one you are having perhaps) when they do pop up and can make debugging very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**

from php.net

- Currently the "@" error-control operator prefix will even disable
  error reporting for critical errors that will terminate script
  execution.
- Among other things, this means that if you use "@" to suppress errors
  from a certain function and either it isn't available or has been
  mistyped, the script will die right there with no indication as to
  why.

from php.net

**a better way to do :**

Customize your own ideas. Only errors between Error-Lines or Error-Numbers

```
<?php

function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline )
{
    if (error_reporting() === 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    //example turn error OFF, between line 100 and 200
    if ($errline<100 || $errline>200) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
    } else return;
}

set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

function catchException($e)
{
    // Do some stuff
}

set_exception_handler('catchException');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im surprised I havent seen Exceptions thrown around yet.

Try/catch is a very effective method of customising runtime errors and exceptions and allowing your code to continue executing rather than halting.

```
class MySQLConnectException extends Exception{
     public function __construct( $message ){
          parent::__construct( $message );
     }
}

try{
    $mysql = new mysqli();
    If( !$mysql )
        Throw new MySQLConnectException('Failed to connect');
}
catch( MySQLConnectException $e ){
    echo $e-> getMessage();
}
```